# Extract text from href attribute of <a> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I extract text from the `href` attribute of `a` tag when I have `а` inside `h4`?

I have something like this:

```
<h4><a href="http://google.com">Search</h4>
<h4><a href="http://yahoo.com">Search2</h4>
```

And I want to have something like this:

```
http://google.com
http://yahoo.com
```

What is the easiest way of achieving this?

Comment: how do you intend to get this information?  E.g., do you want every single one when the page loads, just one when it is clicked on, etc.

Comment: Something like: `$('a').attr('href')`? Did you managed to at least do some search or read **basics** of jQuery? There are thousands of answers to questions like that in the Internet!

Comment: you look like got the same lesson as some other kid here who posted the exact same thing a couple of hours back :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to correct your HTML, `a` elements should always be closed, or else you'll get unexpected results in you JS.

```js
$(function() {
  $('h4>a[href]').each(function() {
    $(this).parent().replaceWith( this.href );
    $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4><a href="http://google.com">Search</a></h4>
<h4><a href="http://yahoo.com">Search2</a></h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get get the `href` `attr`

```
$("h4 a").each(function () {
   alert($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2bpyn7tp/1/

```
$.each( $('h4 > a') , function(){
    $('#result').append( $(this).attr('href') + '<br>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is also incorrect. You have not closed anchor tag in your code.

I think this is what you are looking for.

HTML Code -

```
<h4><a href="http://google.com">Search</a></h4>
<h4><a href="http://yahoo.com">Search2</a></h4>
```

jQuery Code -

```
$('h4').replaceWith(function() {
    return $('h4 a').attr('href');
});
```

Working fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Ashish_developer/szr2pjnb/

Answer (score -1):

Try with this code:

```
var arr = [];
$(function(){
   $("h4 a").each(function () {
      arr.push($(this).attr('href')); //<- Add href in array for further use
   });
   console.log(arr); 
});
```